# Vodafone UK keeps stripping out my custom mobile headers

Tags: mobile, http-headers

Currently doing some work using Vodafone in the UK.

And they can potentially rip the headers out of my ripping the headers out of my mobile requests, see http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/vodafonerant/

I was wondering if anyone has ever used a mobile over the vodafone network and needed to pass custom data i.e a SessionId in the header.
I need to pass the value in the header as it is specific to the mobile platform and the sites webservices are used by other non-mobile consumers that do not require this data, so headers are the perfect place for them... thats when they aren't stripped out by vodafone.

A list of standard headers are 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers

If any of you have used a standard header which you know vodafone does not strip out and can be "repurposed", that would be great to know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have talked to a few people and apparently using the basic access authentication header works well.  So I will be using this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication